# Find object in nested data by property value (with JSONPath)

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

I have this test data:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    l: 'a',
    sub: [
      ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    l: 'b',
    sub: [
      {
        id: 4,
        l: 'd'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        l: 'e'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        l: 'f',
        sub: [
          {
            id: 7,
            l: 'g'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    l: 'c',
    sub: []
  }
];
```

And I'm trying to get the path of the object with `id: 7`. I  tried quite some JSONPath queries, but I just can't seem to fiind out how to make JSONPath iterate over all `sub` keys and search in there.

How can I match the object with `id: 7`?

Here is my testing plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RoSeRo0L1B2oH3wC5LdU?p=preview

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This query should work for what you are doing:

```
$..[?(@.id==7)]
```

You need to remove the id just after the `$..` as you want to select the whole object, not just the id.  You were also missing the square brackets around the query.

This query brings back the following result set:

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "l": "g"
    }
]
```

If you just want to retrieve the value of the l property (since you already know the id), you can easily do that as well. Just add `.l` at the end of the query:

```
$..[?(@.id==7)].l
```

This brings back the following result set:

```
[
    "g"
]
```

I tested the first query out here using this online json path tester tool and using your plunker:
http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathfilterallbypropertyvalue