# JSONPath expressions: getting the value of a specific attribute based on it's presence or the value of another attribute

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have JSON structure that is a nested parent/child kind of structure:

```
{
  "type": "site",
  "profile_id": "site profile id",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "dealer",
      "profile_id": "dealer profile id",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "location",
          "profile_id": "location profile id",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "customer",
              "profile_id": "customer profile id",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "farm",
                  "farm_id": "farm id",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "type": "field",
                      "field_id": "field id"
                     }]}]}]}]}]}
```

Is there some way in JSONPath to do one of the following:

1. give me the profile_id if it's present, or give me the farm_id if
   it's present,    or give me the field_id if it's present.
2. give me the profile_id if type=customer, or give me the farm_id, if type=farm,    or give me the field_id if type=field
3. give me the nth attribute from each class.  The id is actually the third attribute in each class.  This is my least favorite option, because I don't know if the id will always be the third attribute.

Comment: If you are willing to do three JSONPath calls, option 2 would be pretty easy.  Getting the profile_id if type=customer for example would look like this: `$..[?(@.type=='customer')].profile_id`.  See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680515/find-object-in-nested-data-by-property-value-with-jsonpath/30683008#30683008) for another example.  Also, since you may run into issues with this, you are missing some syntax in your JSON, e.g. commas between fields, and double quotes around property names.

Comment: Duncan, this worked fine for my situation.  Also thanks for calling out the syntax. I'll edit the question to improve it.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I'll submit this as an official answer then so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 7):

A solution for option 2 that requires 3 separate queries would be the following.  Here are the 3 queries:

```
$..[?(@.type=='customer')].profile_id
$..[?(@.type=='farm')].farm_id
$..[?(@.type=='field')].field_id
```

I verified these queries with http://www.jsonquerytool.com

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680515/find-object-in-nested-data-by-property-value-with-jsonpath/30683008#30683008) for a similar example.