# Manipulating nested array of obects in RedisJSON

Tags: json, redis, node-redis, redisjson, redislabs

I have a JSON with nested array like below to be saved in Redis. I am using RedisJSON module to save the data as JSON.

```
customer:12345 : {
    info : {
        key1: val1,
        key2: val2,
        key3: val3
    },
    rides: [
        {
            rideid: xxx,
            from: fromval,
            to: toval,
            date: dateofride,
            distance: distanceval,
            points: pointsval
        },
        {
            rideid: yyy,
            from: fromval,
            to: toval,
            date: dateofride,
            distance: distanceval,
            points: pointsval
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I have a case where a new item can be added to the array or the existing one can be edited. I am using node-redis client with express.js. Express app receives only the data which is changed or added in rides array. If the item is already in the array, new data has to replace the existing array item (rideid is the key of each object), else it has to be added to the array. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following JSON document

```
{
    "info": {
        "key1": "val1"
    },
    "rides": [{
            "rideid": "xxx",
            "points": 0
        },
        {
            "rideid": "yyy",
            "points": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is held by the key `customer:12345` in RedisJSON with the following command

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET customer:12345 . "{\"info\": {\"key1\": \"val1\",\"key2\": \"val2\",\"key3\": \"val3\"},\"rides\":[{\"rideid\": \"xxx\",\"points\": 0 },\t{\"rideid\": \"yyy\",\"points\": 10}]}"
```

You can update ride with rideid `yyy` by e.g. incrementing the score by 5 as follows

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.NUMINCRBY customer:12345 "$.rides[?(@.rideid=='yyy')].points" 5
"[15]"
```

`$.rides[?(@.rideid=='yyy')].points` is a JSONPath expression (more [here](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) and [here](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/path/) and also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680515/find-object-in-nested-data-by-property-value-with-jsonpath))

To add a new ride

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.ARRAPPEND customer:12345 $.rides "{\"rideid\": \"zzz\",\"points\": 5 }"
1) (integer) 3
```

All RedisJSON commands can be found [here](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/commands/)